# Passing CSS :host classes to component's elements

Tags: css, angular, sass

This is not about styling child *components* using `ng-deep` or adding a style/class input to the child component, but passing along classes to elements.

I'm trying to pass along the `dropdown-item` class that the `NgbDropdownItem` directive attaches to an element. I have a component that wraps a button with some functionality, and I want the button to receive the `dropdown-item` class as well. My current solution is to give the component the following sass:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/dropdown';

:host.dropdown-item button { // or :host.dropdown-item *
  @extend .dropdown-item;
}
```

It would be nice to be able to pass along any named class from the host to its elements without having to import it, is this possible?

Comment: Try `:host { .dropdown-item button .... `

Comment: From what I understand of Sass, isn't that just alternate syntax for the example I gave?

Comment: Have tried it I said give it try may be it works